# How do I get the Bing Revenue Conversion tracking to work on Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am using Magento 1.9.1. I have Google Analytics ecommerce tracking working fine but the same thing will not work in Bing Ads.

```
<?php

 $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
 $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>

<script>
var amount = <?php echo number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2); ?>;
window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
window.uetq.push({ 'gv': amount,})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
?>
<script>
var amount = <?php echo number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2); ?>;
window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
window.uetq.push({ 'gv': amount, 'gc': 'USD' })
</script>
```